# unable to install ggtree in R version 4.0.5

Tags: r, ggtree

I tried to install ggtree by using command >BiocManager::install("ggtree") but in the end in am getting error >Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
path: C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library
packages:
boot, class, cluster, KernSmooth, lattice, MASS, Matrix, mgcv, nnet, spatial, survival
Old packages: 'cachem', 'stringi', 'tibble', 'xfun'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

First install `rlang`
`install.packages("rlang")`

Then

Bioconductor version

```
library(BiocManager)
BiocManager::install("ggtree")
```

Comment: when i tried it ended up in >Old packages: 'stringi'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:  dialog

Comment: and uppon running the library for ggtree >Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: ...shows up

Comment: when i add a nothing happen the same dialog appear again >a>Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: